# How to store a vector layer as a geojson file in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, jquery

I have some vector layers that I import from geojson files and run some search on them, I want to display only the results of the search as a vector layer.

I am using a jquery form to search, and I get the result but it doesn't show on the map because the page is after that refreshed and the result is lost. I thought of exporting the result in a geojson file this way I can preserve it.

Here is the code for the search it works fine except that the result layer isn't added to the map.

```
jQuery('#default-search').submit(function(event) {

    var Results=[];
    var src=layer.getSource();
    src.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
        if(feature.get('Name')==='some_Name'){
            Results.push(feature);
        }
    });     
    tmp_source=new ol.source.Vector({
                features: Results
                });
    tmp=new ol.layer.Vector({
            title:'temporary layer', 
            source: tmp_source
            });

    map.addLayer(tmp);
    tmp.setVisible(true);

});
```

Is this possible or is there another way easier ?

Comment: try to add 
    event.preventDefault();
as first statement in the function, by this you should be able to prevent the reloading of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Hicham (above).  Your code seems fine (hard to tell without an example of the results returned) but refreshing of a page on a submit suggests a mishandling of the submit event.  (Plenty of Stack Overflow discussion on the topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263852/prevent-form-redirect-or-refresh-on-submit) is one I like).

You might try instead attaching an event handler to the submit function that specifically triggers the function where you do something with the results:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#default-search', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(event.which == 13) { //trigger something with the 'enter' key
    //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long detour to get a solution for this I finally got to the conclusion that we can't write in a file with javascript, and to do so I had to use php with AJAX